# how to clear cell css style and rowspan in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Below is my html table. In first table first tr first cell i have given csstdgreen to td.
and  second cell have csstdgreen with rowspan 3.
I have to clear csstdgreen  and rowspan and like to convert second table tr.
I have loop through table and check cell have csstdgreen and how many rowspan.
if cell have csstdgreen and rowspan then make first table like second table.
How i check css and rowspan in c# server side.I search google but not get.

```
//First Table
<table id="mytable" runat="server">
<tr class="csstablelisttd">
<td>09:00AM</td>
<td class="csstdgreen">00</td>
<td class="csstdgreen" rowspan="3">John</td>
</tr>
<tr class="csstablelisttd">
<td></td>
<td class="csstdgreen">15
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="csstablelisttd">
<td></td>
<td class="csstdgreen">15
</td>
</tr>
</table>

//Second Table
<table id="mytable" runat="server">
<tr class="csstablelisttd">
<td>09:00AM</td>
<td>00</td>
<td>John</td>
</tr>
<tr class="csstablelisttd">
<td></td>
<td>15
</td>
<td></td> 
</tr>
<tr class="csstablelisttd">
<td></td>
<td class="csstdgreen">15
</td>    
<td></td>    
</tr>    
</table>
```

//I m looping through table like this in server code.

```
  for(int i = 0; i <= mytable.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j <= mytable.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
            {
    //error in if conditon object refrence not set to an instance of an object
        if(mytable.Rows[i].Cells[j].Attributes["csstdgreen"].Equals("csstdgreen"))
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: does it has to be server-sided? Tried jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to Remove CssCalss

```
if(Cell1.Attributes["Class"].Equals("csstdgreen"))
 Cell1.Attributes.Remove("Class");
```

To Add CssClass

```
Cell1.Attributes.Add("Class","MyClass");
```

Comment: How to check if cell have csstdgreen cssclass and cell have rowspan or not

Comment: if(Cell1.CssClass == "csstdgreen")

Comment: Cell1 does not have attribute CssClass

Comment: i m looping through table like this

Comment: for(int i = 0; i <= mytable.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
  {
   for(int j = 0; j < mytable.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
   {}}

Comment: Rab Nawaz:error in if conditon object refrence not set to an instance of an object see my updated quetion

Comment: Use if(mytable.Rows[i].Cells[j].Attributes["class"].Equals("csstdgreen"))

Comment: if(mytable.Rows[i].Cells[j].Attributes["class"].Equals("csstdgreen"))
    {
     break;
    }

Comment: i have use above cod also but error object refrence not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Rab What about rowspan if cell have rowspan 3 then i have to do operation on further rows